# WindowState: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#

I am working on a Windows app (running on Windows 10, built with VS2017) which threw the following exception:

The method that caused the exception is:

```
    private void RestoreWindow()
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        this.Width = this.LastSize.Value.Width;
        this.Height = this.LastSize.Value.Height;
        this.Left = this.LastSize.Value.X;
        this.Top = this.LastSize.Value.Y;

        this.LastSize = null;
    }
```

The state change event is handled like so:

```
    private void windowChat_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {
            this.MaxHeight = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            this.MaxWidth = Double.PositiveInfinity;
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that this exception is caused when the object is `NULL`, in this case `WindowState`, but I don't see how that is possible since it is a system property.

The stack trace is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
>   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>   at RestoreWindow() in x.cs:line 324
>   at RestoreButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in x.cs:line 100
>   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: Can we have the full stack trace, please?

Comment: that does seem a little unlikely. isn't that thing just an enum?

Comment: `WindowState` is not a Nullable. The error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Also, is this `windows.forms` or is it WPF?

Comment: @just_another_engineer please post the full body of the method that caused the exception and a complete stack trace. your question is not answerable without it.

Comment: I'd like to post a full stack trace but there's an error about "code not being properly formatted". But I'm not adding any code.

Comment: @just_another_engineer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251183/cannot-figure-why-am-getting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-prop

Please, do not post pictures of stacktraces, just put them in your post as text

Comment: Since you chose to not expose your code I consider this a waste of time here.

Comment: I've added the methods that are used. I cannot expose my code unfortunately. I'm trying to add the stack traces as text, with no luck.

Comment: Finally able to add the stack trace. We are using WPF, not windows forms.

Comment: Have you considered `LastSize` to be `null`?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicated a problem at line 324, which was this line of code:

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

But the issue was with LastSize being null.